# Computing Hausdorff metric for some sets

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Just started to learn about metric spaces, and I came across the Hausdorff metric. Let $K$ be the family of non-empty closed subsets of $[0,1]$. For $A \in K$ and $\delta > 0$ let $A_{\delta}$ be the union of closed intervals of length $2\delta$ centered at points of $A$. Define $d$ by $$ d(A,B) = \inf\left\{\delta > 0: A \subset B_{\delta} \ \text{and} \ B \subset A_{\delta} \right\}. $$

My textbook calls this the Hausdorff metric on the space of nonempty closed subsets of $[0,1]$.

Now let $A = \left\{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \cup \left\{0\right\}, B = [0,1]$ and $C = \left\{1/2\right\}$.

I need to compute $d(A,B), d(B,C)$ and $d(A,C)$.

I think $d(A,B) = 1$. I reasoned as follows: since $A$ also contains the point $0$, $A_{\delta}$ must also contain an interval of the form $[-\delta, \delta]$. Now, for $B$ to be a subset of this, we must have that $\delta = 1$. So $d(A,B) = 1$.

Furthermore, I found $d(B,C) = 1/2$. Since, in this case we have $C_{\delta} = [1/2 - \delta, 1/2 + \delta]$, the smallest $\delta$ such that $B \subset C_{\delta}$ is $1/2$. Same reasoning gives $d(A,C) = 1/2$.

Can someone tell me if these answers are correct? There is another question the textbook provides. It says:

> If we replace the family $K$ with the family of **all** nonempty
>   subsets of $[0,1]$, and define $d$ in the same way, we would not get a
>   metric. Which of the conditions for a metric would fail? What would be
>   the value of $d(A,B)$ if $A = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ and $B = [0,1]$?

I'm not sure how to answer this, and why this would change anything. I see that $A_{\delta}$ would be of the form $A_{\delta} = [q_n - \delta, q_n + \delta]$ for $q_n \in [0,1]$ and $q_n \in \mathbb{Q}$, but now sure how to use this to answer the question.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning for $d(A,B)=1$ is flawed.

$B$ does not need to be a subset of the $2\delta$-interval centered at $0$.

Instead, $B$ needs to be a subset of $A_\delta$ which is equal to the **union** of $2\delta$ intervals centered on all the points of $A$, that is
$$B \subset [0-\delta,0+\delta] \cup \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \,\, \biggl[\frac{1}{n}-\delta,\frac{1}{n}+\delta\biggr]
$$

Here's a hint to how to correct this error. Think about the longest gap in $A$, meaning the longest interval in the complement of the set $A$. The set $B$ contains all points in that gap. How large should $\delta$ be to guarantee that $A_\delta$ contains all points in that gap?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Why should I look at the complement of $A$?

Comment: Because there are points of $A_\delta$ which are in the complement of $A$.

Comment: For example, $\frac{7}{16}$ is in $B$. But $\frac{7}{16}$ is not in $A$, it is in the complement of $A$. The nearest point in $A$ to $\frac{7}{16}$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, which is distance $\delta = \frac{1}{16}$ away from $\frac{7}{16}$. Thus, by examining the point $\frac{7}{16}$, we have proved that the Hausdorff distance between $B$ and $A$ is greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{16}$. By examining other points in the complement of $A$, you might be able to find other lower bounds to the Hausdorff distance between $B$ and $A$. Perhaps you might even be able to deduce its exact value.

Comment: I think $d(A,B) = 1/4$. The set $A$ will contain all sets of the form $  \left\{1,0\right\}, \left\{1/2, 0\right\}, \left\{1/3, 0\right\}, ...$ Now, If I pick $\delta = 1/4$, then $A_{\delta}$ will contain the closed intervals $[1 - 1/4, 1 + 1/4], [1/2 - 1/4, 1/2 + 1/4], \ldots$. This will ensure all the points of $B$ are included. Is this correct?

Comment: That's correct, $d(A,B)=1/4$. Your argument shows explicitly that $d(A,B) \le 1/4$, and I'll bet you can also see why $d(A,B) \ge 1/4$.